# Bisection doesn't return a value

Tags: matlab, function, while-loop, bisection, convergence

The function below, `bisection`, is supposed to find a root given three inputs: a function `f`, and an interval defined using the two parameters `a` and `b`. The intention is that the value of `a` and `b` are changed within the function to approach a common point, as long as their signs are different.

When I call my function like this:

```
bisection( @(x)x-1 ,-2,3)
```

no output is returned. What am I doing wrong?

```
function X = bisection(f,a,b)

if ge((f(a)*f(b)),0)

    disp('Wrong')

    return;
end

X = (a+b)/2;
while abs(X)>0.01

    if f(X)*f(a)>0
        X=a;
    else 
        X=b;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the Infinite!

Well done! You've written your first (and not last, believe me) infinite loop. The problem is threefold. Firstly your stop condition was `abs(X)` and should have been `abs(f(X))` - you don't care for `X` to be zero, you want `f(X)` to be zeros. Secondly you don't update your your `X` correctly so your break condition is never hit (unless you are lucky to give this function symmetrical `a,b` bounds around the zero of the function). You could see this easily by adding a line like `disp(f(X)); pause(0.5);` somewhere in the while-loop.

In general try to avoid infinite loops with some explicit stop condition. In my code below I've put in the interaction limit past which the algorithm will just stop (it would be more elegant to catch that condition and warn the user of hitting the iteration limit...).

```
function x0 = bisection(f,a,b)
assert(f(a)*f(b)<0,'Invalid f(x) range. f(a)*f(b) >= 0');

tol = 0.00001; % Tolerance
iter_limit = 10000; % Limit of number of iterations

iter = 0;
x0 = (a+b)/2; % Midpoint
while abs(f(x0)) > tol && iter < iter_limit
    if f(x0)*f(a) > 0
        a = x0; % Zero to the right of the midpoint
    else 
        b = x0; % Zero to the left
    end

    x0 = (a+b)/2; % Recalculate midpoint
    iter = iter + 1;
end
end
```

This should work no problem with

```
f = @(x)x-1;
bisection(f,-2,3);
```

I get something like 0.999992370... which is within specified tolerance from the actual answer (1).

Comment: Dziękuję (assuming you're polish:) )!

If not - Thank you!

adding a extra end-notation and also updating my X accordingly to your suggestion made it work. Just one last question though. Why is "iter" necessary? Wouldn't it be sufficent to only have a limit for my tol? What does the iter add?

Comment: @oxodo the reason for specifying `iter` is to ensure that the algorithm returns a value. Imagine a highly fluctuating function (like `x = linspace(0,2*pi,1E4); y = sin(1E2*x); figure(); plot(x,y);`, but worse) so even if the bisection progresses _somewhere_ each step, it still is never "truly done" because there's always a smaller subdivision. For practical purposes, such precision doesn't matter of course, but the computer can't know that, so we limit it. Also, in terms of debugging, if the iteration limit is exceeded, you should revisit your algorithm because it might have a logical fault.

Comment: "*You've written your first (and not last, believe me) infinite loop*" Right in the feels.